# Flutter inter-app communication using service

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would like to create two different flutter app package (Android only if limited), one of which would just act as foreground/background service without any UI, the other one would access/ trigger the service(1st app) to run some logic of that.
Majority of the coding of both app is to be done in dart with as little native code as possible.

Is there a way to achieve that?

In android there is Intent that can access other app services, I want something like that.